# Firefox XUI textbox autocomplete inside add-on?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am creating a tagging add-on for Firefox and want a text box to autocomplete in a similar way to the 'tags' field on firefoxes own bookmark popup. Is this possible?

If the XUI textbox component cant do this, is it possible to have 'normal' form components somewhere on the chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the XUL `<textbox type="autocomplete" autocompletesearch="...">` component.

You will at the very least have to create an XPCOM component that generates the autocomplete results. Both the current value and the `autocompletesearchparam` attribute are provided to the search component which it can then use to influence the results if necessary.

There is a [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_implement_custom_autocomplete_search_component) on this although it's possible that it's a little out of date.